# Possible to rate an iOS App within the App?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

Is it possible to have a user rate your app within the app their using (e.g., without having to go into the AppStore app) on the iOS device?

Thanks!

Edit: I know about Appirater, but that takes the user outside of the current app when they want they agree to rate your app.

Comment: No. You can popup an alert suggesting that they rate your app and give them a link that takes them there.

Comment: I could've sworn I saw a popup in the Facebook app that prompted for a star rating and a review, but I can't replicate that popup anymore.  Any chance they figured out a way to circumvent the need to go to the iTunes store, or do you think they're just soliciting app review for their own internal benefit?

Comment: Hah, I asked this question almost three years ago. I know what you're talking about. I think I saw the same thing in Flappy Birds before it was taken down. I didn't figure it out. After three years of development, I've come to believe that using things like Appirater, or my own Panhandler library, causes a poor end-user experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I'm afraid not. If Apple allowed this (*and I highly doubt they ever will*) then it would be open to abuse and unsolicited positive reviews would be rife.

Reviewing is a user driven process that requires they be logged with their Apple ID, and can be accessed only via the App Store.

Comment: I figured this was the case from all the google queries I performed. I just wanted to get external confirmation from other developers. Thank you!

Comment: iOS 5 allows you to do it in GameCenter

Comment: @javy Not sure how this helps the person asking the question? GameCenter is not their app, which they specifically referred to their question, it's Apple's. Also, GameCenter is game specific, therefore only games, with GameCenter support, can be reviewed through it.

Comment: @micpringle Nowhere in his question does he indicate his app can't use game center or isn't a game.  Did he edit the question and remove what you may have read?  I'm simply offering a possibility as I have no idea what kind of an app it is, game, utility, or otherwise.

Comment: @javy No, but he specifically refers to his app as an app, twice, so the assumption was made it wasn't a game. He also specifically asks about rating from within his app, and having to go from his app to GameCenter gives exactly the same experience of going from his app to the App Store which he states he specifically wants to avoid.

Comment: Your point is understandable.  My suggestion is only to offer different ways of achieving his goal.

Comment: @micpringle if the app has Game Center integration, you CAN rate it from with in the app. which gives a bit of hope that apple may end up offering an API for rating an app from within the app...

Comment: @Epaga Apple will never offer an API for rating an app from within an app until they can eliminate the existing rating fraud that happens using bots and the like on the App Store itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the user report ratings to a server so that you can see, but you can't have the user rate to iTunes within the app. If this was possible I'm sure people would find a way to automatically rate 5 stars the second they open the app. You can, however, make a pop-up appear asking the user rate with a button that takes them into the App Store.